# How can I reset my Windows 10 PC, but keep drivers?

Tags: drivers, windows-10, reset

I ordered an [ASUS Notebook](http://www.asus.com/US/Notebooks/ASUS_EeeBook_X205TA/) as a Christmas present for my brother, and I've been working on optimizing and updating it.  I've done all the work I needed to do, and now I want to reset the PC, so it will enter into the OOBE (out of the box experience) when he opens it.  Unfortunately, when I choose to reset the PC (and keep files), I'm warned that several apps will **not** be kept, including:

- The network driver
- Trackpad gesture support
- Graphics driver
- Audio driver

How can I reset the PC, but keep the drivers that I've installed, so that I do not have to work on the PC (I.E. reinstall drivers) the entire morning after he unwraps it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a utility called Sysprep designed for doing exactly this, and it comes with Windows. Navigate to `C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\` and run `Sysprep.exe`. Make sure it's set to prep the system for OOBE and that the system will shut down after the procedure.

[image: sysprep]

Press OK when ready.

Comment: @Ben-N I used it but the old user is still there after doing that. Any idea how to get rid of the old user and let OOBE ask for a new one? I already have a question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1320453/old-user-still-there-in-oobe-after-sysprep-and-deleting-it